# How do I make an "___ing" word modify the noun I mean it to modify?

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds, participles, present-participles, gerund-clauses

I want to use "listening" such that it modifies "the vogue", not "the people."

Which sentence achieves that? Or neither?

Sentence I

> The vogue of people listening to music on tapes is not completely
>   gone.

Sentence II

> The vogue of people's listening to music on tapes is not completely
>   gone.

So "the vogue" is the act of listening music on tape.

I also don't know what **"listening"** would be grammatically called in each sentence: **"gerund" or "participle"?**.

Comment: If you get difficulties with formulating your idea don't cling to the difficult formulation. Try to say it in another simpler way as:  There are still people who listen to music on tapes

Comment: Can you explain more about the difference between the two meanings that you have in mind? I don't understand the distinction.

Comment: Instead of "vogue",  use "**cult**", there is nothing "fashionable", "trendy" or "stylish"  about listening to audio tapes. "Vogue" in this context sounds wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say *"the vogue listening to music"*, so there is no way that *listening* can modify *vogue* in the above sentence. You need a preposition.

You can say *"the vogue **for** listening to music"*, so the proper way to phrase the sentence is

> the vogue of people for listening to music ...

(You can also say *"the vogue **of** listening to music"*, but it's best to avoid using two ***of***'s if you can.)

I actually don't see why you need *of people* in this sentence at all ... who else is going to have a vogue for listening to music?

Answer (score 0):

- Sentence I: *The vogue of people **listening** to music on tapes is not completely gone = ... people **who listen** to music ...*
  This is a participle clause.
- Sentence II: *The vogue of **people's listening** to music on tapes is not completely gone.*
  This sounds a bit weird, but *listening* is a noun in this case.